# Erlang unlinked process terminates

Tags: erlang

If I have a process A that makes call to a function in process B (procB:func().), and func() generates an error during execution. Process B would terminate, but what about process A? Consider the following in process A:

Case 1:

```
 {ok, Reply} = procB:func().
```

Case 2:

```
 procB:func().
```

Will process A terminate in both cases? Or just in case 1 because of mismatch? Please note that the two processes are not linked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is procB? is it module? in this case func() will be executed in the process A. If procB is some registered name of process, you cannot call func() in the procB this way. You need to send a message to procB and wait for response.

Comment: `procB:func()` is a call to another _module_, not necessarily a call to another _process_.  The answer to this question depends on what `procB:func` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as calling a function in another process, you can send a message to a process that it then may choose to call a function based on message content.

gen_servers work this way, you send a message to the gen_server, and it does a match on the message and chooses if it should invoke call/cast/info/terminate functions.

Assuming you are really talking about sending a message from A to B and B decides to exit, it's all about if process A is linked/monitoring process B.

If you monitor B, you are sent a message saying that B went down and the reason.
If you are linked to B, I believe the rule is you are killed if B died with a status other than 'normal'

A could also have set the flag trap_exit, which means that even if linked and B dies, A is sent a message that he should die and you get to interact with that message (ie: you may restart B, if you choose)

[learn you some erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes) has a good tutorial on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to call function in another process. That is the beauty of Erlang: all communication between processes is via message passing. People sometimes confuse modules with processes. I even wrote [article about it](http://tkowal.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/erlang-otp-gen_server-boilerplate/).

For example process A:

- spawns process B
- sends message which is for example tuple `{fun_to_call, Args, self()}` (you need the `self()` to know, where to respond
- waits for reply using `receive`

Process B:

- immediately after start waits for message
- when receives message, does some computation and sends response back

This looks like a lot of boilerplate, so this exact pattern is abstracted in [`gen_server`](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/clients-and-servers)